# Parse Error: unexpected '}' while creating Shortcode with Loop

Tags: shortcode, parse

I think either I am quite stupid today or just work-blind by this project but I've been trying to fix a little error a new shortcode is causing.

This is the code

```
<?php function reviewslide_function() {
    $output .= '
    <!-- Review Injection -->
    <div id="reviews" class="p-full">
        <div class="section_head">
            <span class="eyebrow">You about us</span>
            <h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="stars">
            <span class="material-icons">grade</span>
            <span class="material-icons">grade</span>
            <span class="material-icons">grade</span>
            <span class="material-icons">grade</span>
            <span class="material-icons">grade</span>
        </div>
        <div id="reviewbox">';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'review',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $output .= '
        <div class="review">'.
        the_content().
        '<span class="review_author">'. 
        bewerter_get_meta( "bewerter_name" ).
        '</span></div>';
    enwhile;
    $output .= '
    </div>
        <script>jQuery("#reviewbox > div:gt(0)").hide();
        
            setInterval(function() {
                jQuery("#reviewbox > div:first")
                .fadeOut(1800)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(2000)
                .end()
                .appendTo("#reviewbox");
            },  6000);
        </script>
        <div class="reviewbtn btn btn_blue arrow_r nosmooth">
            <a href="~GOOGLEREVIEWLINK~" target="_blank"><span>All Reviews</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Review Exit -->';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('reviews', 'reviewslide_function'); ?>
```

This is the error thrown at me:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /html/wordpress-dev/wp-content/plugins/cpt-review/index.php on line 187
```

I am getting mad crazy trying to fix this, I just seem to be unable to find the error in here.

Comment: Correct `enwhile` typo to `endwhile` and everything should be ok.

Comment: @IvanShatsky can you post that as an answer? I can't give you upvote rep points for a comment :(

Comment: @IvanShatsky oh my god! Thank you so much. It's always the tiniest things that end up making me lose my hairs. Thank you so much. Would appreciate it if you post this as an answer so I can upvote and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your code (`enwhile` instead of `endwhile`) so PHP is complaining because of non-closed `while` loop. Correct it and everything should be ok.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ivan!